# Java: Using Objects Constructed in A Previous Method

Tags: java, oop

I am creating a program that contains a Count object with certain associated fields and methods.

In the program, the Count object is initialized in the setupCounter() method, while its methods are actually used in the counterControl() method.

However, when I attempt to call the Count instance I previously initialized in the setupCounter() method, I am told that "count cannot be resolved", so I assume the instance of Count that was created only has a local scope.

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue of the insufficient scope of the Counter instance? Below is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    setupCounter();
    for (;;) {
      counterControl();
    }

  }

  public static void setupCounter() {
    int startVal;
    int incrementVal;

    System.out.println("Please enter the starting value of the counter:");
    startVal = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the increment/decrement amount on the counter:");
    incrementVal = in.nextInt();

    Count count = new Count(startVal, incrementVal);
  }

  public static void counterControl() {
    String control;

    System.out.println("The following controls can be applied to the counter:");
    System.out.println("Increment - i");
    System.out.println("Decrement - d");
    System.out.println("Exit - x");

    control = in.nextLine();

    switch (control) {
      case "i":
        count.increment();
        break;
      case "d":
        count.decrement();
        break;
      case "x":
        System.exit(0);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answers are close. Amir simply forgot to change the method signature of setupCounter() from a return of void to Count.

Basically, you just need to have a static variable to keep a reference to the Count object you created. Why does it need to be static? Because the methods that use it (e.g. counterControl() are static).

```
public class Main {
  static Count count;

  ....

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    count = setupCounter();
    for (;;) {
      counterControl();
    }

  }

  public static Count setupCounter() {
    ...    
    return new Count(startVal, incrementVal);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Count counter = setupCounter();
    //now you can refer to counter

....

  public static Count setupCounter() {
    int startVal;
    int incrementVal;

    System.out.println("Please enter the starting value of the counter:");
    startVal = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the increment/decrement amount on the counter:");
    incrementVal = in.nextInt();

    return new Count(startVal, incrementVal);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't returning anything. You must use the "return" keyword at the end of your function in order for it to pass it along.

If it's a void function (like the one you have), it won't return/pass anything, hence the word "void".

EDIT: you may also be aware that you are using the function as a static function. Please look further into static functions and their purposes for better understanding.

EDIT 2: if you are returning data that is of the "Count" type, you should replace void and static with the "Count"

Answer (score 0):

You have various broken things in your code. I have created the count class for you that I think you are missing. And fixed your methods up a bit...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main2 {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Count count = setupCounter();
        for (;;) {
            counterControl(count);
        }

    }

    public static Count setupCounter() {
        int startVal;
        int incrementVal;

        System.out.println("Please enter the starting value of the counter:");
        startVal = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the increment/decrement amount on the counter:");
        incrementVal = in.nextInt();

        return new Count(startVal, incrementVal);
    }

    public static void counterControl(Count count) {
        String control;

        System.out.println("The following controls can be applied to the counter:");
        System.out.println("Increment - i");
        System.out.println("Decrement - d");
        System.out.println("Exit - x");

        control = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(count.getVal());

        switch (control) {
            case "i":
                count.increment();
                break;
            case "d":
                count.decrement();
                break;
            case "x":
                System.exit(0);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static class Count {

    private int startVal, incrementVal;
    private Count(int startVal, int incrementVal) {
        this.startVal = startVal;
        this.incrementVal = incrementVal;
    }

    private void increment() {
        this.startVal += this.incrementVal;
    }

    private void decrement() {
        this.startVal -= this.incrementVal;
    }
    private int getVal(){
        return val;
    }
    }
}
```

Or you could also do this... which is more what you where trying to do, but is not as nice of "java"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main2 {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Count count;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setupCounter();
        for (;;) {
            counterControl();
        }

    }

    public static void setupCounter() {
        int startVal;
        int incrementVal;

        System.out.println("Please enter the starting value of the counter:");
        startVal = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the increment/decrement amount on the counter:");
        incrementVal = in.nextInt();

        count = new Count(startVal, incrementVal);
    }

    public static void counterControl() {
        String control;

        System.out.println("The following controls can be applied to the counter:");
        System.out.println("Increment - i");
        System.out.println("Decrement - d");
        System.out.println("Exit - x");

        control = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println(count.getVal());
        switch (control) {
            case "i":
                count.increment();
                break;
            case "d":
                count.decrement();
                break;
            case "x":
                System.exit(0);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static class Count {

        private int val, incrementVal;
        private Count(int startVal, int incrementVal) {
            this.val = startVal;
            this.incrementVal = incrementVal;
        }

        private void increment() {
            this.val += this.incrementVal;
        }

        private void decrement() {
            this.val -= this.incrementVal;
        }
        private int getVal(){
            return val;
        }
    }
}
```